# Is there software that lets you stream music from your computer to an iPhone over the web?

Tags: macos, iphone, music, streaming

I'm looking for software that does the following:

- Runs some sort of server on the notebook that I point at where I keep my music files.
- Comes with an app or Web UI that lets me browse and play those files on an iPhone over the internet. (For instance from home to the workplace.)

Googling around gives me either programs that only work over a local WiFi network, or HTPC software that stream content *from* the internet to computers/devices on a home network. Also, several hacks involving directory browsing in a regular web server, and [Orb](http://www.orb.com/).

I'd like to have something less crude than the former, and if possible an alternative to the latter.

iTunes integration and NAT traversal of some sort would be nice to have but not really necessary, true streaming* would be *really* nice to have, the only hard requirement is the server part has to run on OS X.

(SO seems to think the question appears subjective, so to clarify: I'm not asking for a debate on what the best setup is, just a list of options I can investigate.)

<sub>*I.e. letting me play a track from the middle without buffering it to that point - I listen to a lot of mixed sets.</sub>

Comment: Find some sample code that will allow you to build a website that can stream music , next setup your notebook as a webserver and deploy the site , register ur ipaddress at some free dns service and you are good to go .

Comment: Note: AudioGalaxy, suggested on the answers, is not available any longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplify Media is bloody brilliant. Recently acquired by an unknown company called Google.
Audiogalaxy 2.0 is also great. I don't know if they have changed it in the last moments, but I believe it only cached music for 30 secs so you would want to have solid access to the Internet. Recommended.

Air Video is another brilliant iphone app for, you guessed it, video streaming.

Comment: I went with Audiogalaxy and Air Video and I like both. Sorry for the delay in accepting, Chrome and SU don't seem to like each other for some reason right now.

Comment: Note: AudioGalaxy is not available any longer.

Answer (score 2):

**[Audiogalaxy](http://www.audiogalaxy.com/)** is exactly what you're looking for - they have both a Web interface and an app for the iPhone/iPod Touch.  I've used it myself and it streams great!

> Audiogalaxy's new cloud music player puts all your music and playlists at your fingertips from any computer or mobile phone. No syncing, no copying, no uploading. Just streaming.

Comment: if Audiogalaxy is the way you want to go, @Sii, please mark @Maclovin's answer as accepted, because he mentioned it first...Thanks!

Comment: On the other hand, AudioGalaxy is not available any longer...